# Table's alias created in FROM clause isn't recognized in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

The task is "Find the university Id where the number of employees
graduated from that university is maximum over all university"

The schemas is like this

```
Graduate ( EmpId: NUMERIC REFERENCES Employee(EmpId), 
           UnivId: NUMERIC REFERENCES University(UnivId), 
           GradYear: NUMERIC)

University ( UnivId: NUMERIC, UnivName: VARCHAR(40))

Employee (EmpId: NUMERIC, 
          EmpName: VARCHAR(40))
```

My query:

```
     SELECT Temp.UnivId
     FROM  (SELECT G.UnivId, COUNT(*) as Num
            FROM Graduate G, Employee E
            WHERE G.EmpId = E.EmpId
            GROUP BY G.UnivId) AS Temp
     WHERE Temp.Num = (SELECT MAX(Temp.Num) FROM Temp);
```

When I run this query in psql console and the software is PostgresSQL, it return an error say *relation "temp" does not exist* and it point the *Temp* at the very end. Does anyone knows why ?

Comment: Because that relation name is not visible to reference in the subquery that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `RANK` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT g.UnivId, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(e.EmpId) DESC) rnk
    FROM Graduate g
    INNER JOIN Employee e
        ON g.EmpId = e.EmpId
    GROUP BY g.UnivId
)

SELECT UnivId
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note that this approach also handles ties nicely, should they occur.

The problem with your current approach is that you are referring to the subquery in the `WHERE` clause as if it's a standalone table, which it is not.  You could move the `Temp` subquery to a CTE, and then your approach can be made to work:

```sql
WITH Temp AS (
    SELECT G.UnivId, COUNT(*) as Num
    FROM Graduate G, Employee E
    WHERE G.EmpId = E.EmpId
    GROUP BY G.UnivId
)

SELECT Temp.UnivId
FROM Temp
WHERE Temp.Num = (SELECT MAX(Temp.Num) FROM Temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be simpler. Move your subquery into a CTE then order by `num` descending and pick the topmost result. You do not need to join `Graduate` and `Employee` too.
Btw `temp` is a reserved word so better do not use it as an identifier/name.

```sql
with tmp as
(
 select univid, count(*) as num
 from graduate
 group by univid
)
select univid
from tmp
order by num desc limit 1;
```

I think that CTEs make SQL code more readable yet you can write the same without a CTE.

```sql
select univid
from 
(
 select univid, count(*) as num
 from graduate
 group by univid
) tmp
order by num desc limit 1;
```

However if ties are an issue you better use the `rank` approach of @TimBiegeleisen, still w/o the `join`.

Answer (score 1):

You can access columns of the query you have aliased `Temp`, but you cannot select from it, because you have not created a view. If you want to create an ad-hoc view, use a `WITH` clause for this.

You should not use comma separated joins by the way. This was the syntax used in the 1980s and some years on until explicit joins (`[INNER] JOIN`, `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, etc.) made it into the SQL standard in 1992. Why join the employee table anyway?

Here is one way to solve this:

```
select univid, count(*)
from graduate
group by univid
order by count(*) desc
fetch first row with ties;
```

Here is another:

```
select univid, cnt
from
(
  select univid, count(*) as cnt, max(count(*)) over () as max_cnt
  from graduate
  group by univid
) t
where cnt = max_cnt;
```

And here is what you tried:

```
with t as
(
  select univid, count(*) as cnt
  from graduate
  group by univid
)
select *
from t
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from t);
```